# Проблемы с кодировкой в моём чате

Tags: php, javascript, кодировка

Здравствуйте, я создал чат с помощью php и javascript.

Чат в сайт вставляется инклудом, чтобы не обновлять каждый раз чат для новых сообщений, на Хроме всё отлично, а на остальных браузерах беда с кодировкой. Помогите разобраться, где влепить кириллицу или что-то исправить? В chat-include.php (сам чат) кодировка вроде указана, на самой странице чата тоже есть кодировка... Вот [тест сайта](http://lifesims.ru/myportfoliosites/thesimstowns/chat.php).

Comment: обновлять каждую секунду чат - как-то не хорошо:( Никакой сервер такого не выдержит

Comment: @ROOT как это не выдержит? Его же выдерживает?

Comment: это если пока один-два пользователя. А вообще я ошибся - там интервал обновления не одна секунда, а 100 миллисекунд (0.1 секунда)

Comment: @uWeb, ваше сообщение содержит ответ? Мне кажется, нет.

Answer (score 1):

Файл .htaccess в корень сайта с директивой:

```
AddDefaultCharset windows-1251
```

Сразу после соединения с БД sql запрос:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES cp1251");
```

На 1920х1280 с сайтом творится ужоооос.